# In my flutter project the assets folder shows "assets\images" is it an error?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEQm6.png)

here you can see. I am using Visual Stdio Code for Flutter development.

I want to create the file like "assets/images" . Already i delete and recreate the file for several times but the problem is not going. That's why code shows some error I already serach on Stack Overflow but I couldn't find the probable solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Please rename your folder from "aasets" to "assets" and then

```
  assets:
        - assets/images/
```

add it like this in pubspec.yaml

Note: please add all subfolders(if you create more than 1) of assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

that is how vscode shows folder structure when there is only one subfolder, for example if you create another folder under assets it will look normal.

Comment: Have you encountered such a problem brother?